# Using iOS 3d Mixer

Tags: iphone, ios, audiounit

I have a AUGraph setup fairly simply with a multichannel mixer connected to an I/O unit.  The playback is accessed through a callback function and everything works nicely.

I am trying to switch over to the 3D Mixer instead of the Multichannel mixer.  So I switched the parameter from kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer to kAudioUnitSubType_AU3DMixerEmbedded and left all the other setup the same.

The result was sort of a high pitched whine that seemed to start sounding like something then became just whine-ish.  I have gone through each of the 3D Mixer unit's [parameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiounit/audio_unit_parameters) and set them to their defaults but there was no change.  Flipping on and off the k3DMixerParam_Enable parameter did work at muting and unmuting the playback though.

What setup I might have missed?  or know where to find an example of a working 3d Mixer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out the 3d mixer needs mono inputs. But you also have to use UInt16 as the input sample data type. This is a working AudioStreamBasicDescription:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat = {0};
size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof (UInt16);

streamFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
streamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = bytesPerSample;
streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = bytesPerSample;
streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * bytesPerSample;
streamFormat.mSampleRate        = graphSampleRate;

// Set the input stream format of the desired 3D mixer unit audio bus
AudioUnitSetProperty (
                      mixerUnit,
                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                      kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                      audioBus,
                      &streamFormat,
                      sizeof (streamFormat)
                      );
```

Comment: Although this is implicit in this example the big endian flag must be off.

Answer (score 1):

As all answers already mention: the 3D Mixer on iOS needs mono inputs.

On iOS 8 / Xcode 6, the concept of canonical formats is deprecated and I found this (and only this) mono stream format description working as 3D Mixer input bus stream format description:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription monoStreamFormat = {0};
monoStreamFormat.mSampleRate        = sampleRate;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
monoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 16;
monoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = 2;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = 2;
```

The sample rate should be set and then obtained from the `AVAudioSession`.

Set this format on the output of the Audio Unit connected to the 3D Mixer input. Which is probably a AUConverter Unit...

Note however, this hasn't been tested for < iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

The 3d Mixer needed mono inputs.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2010/Sep/msg00144.html

Comment: Hey when setting stream format for its input element it gives error to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722158/runtime-exception-while-setting-audio-units-3dmixer-stream-format-in-ios ? any idea y ?